# Issue On Validating Text Field Using Custom Validation Function

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation

Can you please take a look at [This Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Behseini/mrj3vvrj/1/) and let me know what I am doing wrong in this Custom Function to validate the Text input?

```
$(function () {
    var fname = $('#fname').val();
    var lname = $('#lname').val();
    var proceed = true;

    function nameInput(inputData) {
        var textBox = $.trim($(inputData).val())
        if (textBox == "") {
         alert('Field Can Not be Empty');
        }
    }

    $("#pro").on("click", function (e) {
        nameInput(fname);
        e.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

apparently the `nameInput()` is returning `Field Can Not be Empty` in both empty and filled format of the `fname` input. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to remove the two calls to `val()` when you declare your field variables:

```
var fname = $('#fname');
var lname = $('#lname');
```

As it is, you're passing the value to your method, and then in your method calling `val()` again.

Comment: Thanks Robby it is working now but I am really confused here! I tried to keep the variables as they are and updating the function as `var textBox = $.trim(inputData);` but it didn't work!

Comment: Indeed, because they are initialized only once when your outer function is first loaded/executed. If you update the values afterwards, it will not be reflected in the variables.